# Unity3D cloud build failing with Player export failed

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is pretty strange. Both Android and iOS builds fail with pretty much the same message. No errors are shown in the full log. The closest to errors is what I added below. I believe the build stopped working once we added in the Facebook SDK (which is why I included the line about FacebookSettings) but there were so many changes done in the check in, it's hard to be certain.

The Player export failed below is the only line that was in red.
I would think the MissingMethodException would be the cause but that doesn't show as an error.

The build has been broken for several days now which is really, really bad.

> 201: [Unity] Script attached to 'FacebookSettings' in scene '' is missing or no valid script is attached.
>   202: [Unity] WARNING: PVRTC texture format is not supported, decompressing texture
>   203: [Unity] WARNING: PVRTC texture format is not supported, decompressing texture
>   204: [Unity] UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
>   205: [Unity] MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.get_applicationIdentifier'.
>   206: [Unity] Player export failed. Reason: PostProcessBuild callback threw exception
>   207: ! build of 'default-ios' failed. compile failed
>   208: publishing finished successfully.
>   209: Finished: FAILURE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted for both the SDK itself, and the additional pages for iOS and Android?

Comment: It builds fine locally for both iOS and Android. The issue seems to only come up with the cloud build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the issue was the build version on the cloud. The build was set to use the latest 5.5, but the project was upgraded to 5.6. After changing the cloud build to use Latest 5.6, the build succeeded